# How to show the sum of the entered responses in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create a simple form in google to enter a value. I would like to show in the form the total of all submitted values. How can I do that?

I can calculate the total in a cell (in the responses form), how can I retrieve the value of this cell?

Comment: if the existing answer doesn't resolve your issue please provide a minimal reproducible example. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's a simple modeless dialog with the value of Sheet1!A1 displayed in it.

```
function launchMySimpleDialog() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sum = sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<p>${sum}</p>`),'Dialog Title')
}
```

Example:

[image]